# Sphinx custom directive parsing markdown

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, docutils, myst

So, I know I can invoke parsing of a content nested in a directive via [nested_parse](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/markupapi.html#parsing-directive-content-as-rest), namely:

```py
vl = docutils.statemachine.ViewList(inputLines, source=self.content.source, parent=self.content, parent_offset=0)
self.state.nested_parse(vl, 0, section)
```

However, this assumes the input I pass to it is in RST. I tried something like

```py
parser = MystParser()
docu = docutils.utils.new_document(".")
parser.parse("**Some Markdown** `goes here`", docu)
```

...which I found in some documentation samples, but it fails on `docu` missing some attributes. Moreover, I do not really want to create a new document; just append content to an existing node.

Is there any way to nested parse Markdown explicitly from within a directive? I use the latest sphinx docker image `sphinxdoc/sphinx:latest`.

**EDIT:**
I also tried

```py
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    tmp.write(schemaObject["description"].encode("utf-8"))
    content = f"""
.. include:: "{tmp.name}"
   :parser: myst_parser.sphinx_
"""
    vl = docutils.statemachine.ViewList(content.splitlines(), source=self.content.source, parent=self.content, parent_offset=0)
    self.state.nested_parse(vl, 0, section)
```

but for some reason, I get

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I eventually found a working solution. Not proud of it.

```py
from sphinx.util.docutils import new_document
from docutils import nodes
from myst_parser.parsers.sphinx_ import MystParser


# within the directive run(self)
title = nodes.title(text=schemaTitle)
section = nodes.section(ids=title)
section += title

parser = MystParser()
document = new_document(".")
document.settings.env = self.env
parser.parse("..my markdown content", document)
section += document.children
```